# Get all the users who are Site owners in Office 365 tenant

Tags: rest, office365, sharepoint-online

I am looking for a way to fetch all the sites where the logged in user is site owner .I tried using Graph API but looks like there is no supportive filter to fetch/enumerate all the sites .

I want this to be fetched in a few seconds .Did anybody tried on this ?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can get the all information in relation to sites:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites
```

And then you can try the following query to filter the site information:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?select=siteCollection,webUrl&filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null
or
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/sites
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/
```

The $filter don't work for the query now.

Some official docs:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/site_list
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/site_search

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites --This is returning a bunch of data services ...nothing on sites.I have all the required permission.

Comment: Owner information is not currently present in any of the suggestions listed above.